# How can I check wifi activity?

Tags: network, wifi

I have a LAN network with three computers connecting to the Internet both through wired and encrypted wifi connections. Is there a way I can check who is connecting to the Internet via the wifi connection?

Comment: What wireless router/access point do you have? I know my dlink will let me look at that through it's web interface.

Comment: It's the router my isp provides, not sure who the manufacturer is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the wireless routers I'm familiar with, there is an admin page that lists the MAC addresses of devices that are connected. Take this with a grain of salt: a malicious user could easily change the MAC address (to either look like one of your devices, or so that it appears to be a completely different device each time he connects).

Answer (score 1):

In general, most wireless routers will offer an admin page as per @bstpierre's answer. An alternative on higher end routers is to use SNMP (have a look at [this blog post](http://www.david-guerrero.com/papers/snmp/) for some information) - which can make it easier to script for automated stats/alerting.

Comment: Of course, this requires that *all* of the computers on your network are under your administrative control.

Comment: It would help, although even just pulling off the router info through SNMP could be informative.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to know the purpose of the connection data. The AP will have logs, you could poll the computer's interfaces for activity, or you could set up a monitor on the wifi.

Cace Technology (now Riverbed) has [Cascade Pilot](http://www.riverbed.com/us/products/cascade/wireshark_enhancements/cascade_pilot_personal_edition.php) that can be used (with a wireless packet capture nic) to monitor wifi activity. That way you can know who is connecting, even if it is not those 3 expected hosts. There are also built-in reporting and monitoring features.